# Utility of RequestParam in a rest web application

Tags: spring, spring-restcontroller

I use spring boot in a rest architecture, Is it still usefull to use requestparam in a rest spring application?

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<Page<Cars>> getCars(Integer carId){
 ....
}

@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<Page<Cars>> getCars(@RequestParam(value = "carId", required = false)  Integer carId){
 ....
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it... REST doesn't mean abandon the defaults for the web.

Comment: use it or not don't seem to change anything in a rest application